# Check if float value is integer

Tags: objective-c, floating-point, numbers

In Objective C, how can I check if value is integer number like 2.000 , 3.000, 8.000 stored as a float, and not a fraction like 2.456, 3.578

Comment: "a [perfect number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number) is a positive integer that is equal to the sum of its proper positive divisors" All you want to know is if it has decimals or not, am I correct?

Comment: You need to define whether you mean an exact integer (which is possible in IEEE float but not some other float formats) or simply something that appears to be an integer to a given level of precision.

Comment: @HotLicks I have float number which increases from 0.000 to 12.000. I want to fire action when number is integer like 1.000,2.000 etc.

Comment: And you increase it in what size increments?

Comment: increases randomly, the values may like 0.000 , 0.012, 0.157, 0.587 etc. its an angle actually, which increases withy respect to touch

Comment: @SourabhKumbhar Adding random fractions which are not exactly representable, such as 0.012, 0.157, 0.587, is very unlikely to result in an exact integer. You should probably allow a range around each integer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think you're asking how to find out if a number stored as a `float` is an integer. There are a number of techniques. Here's one:

```
if(fVal == floorf(fVal))
    ... // do something
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this!! I have been trying for the last two days to achieve this basic functionality and failed (lol).... You are a life saver!!

Answer (score 14):

Use the floating point remainder function:

```
if (fmod(fVal, 1.0) == 0.0)
   // is integer
```

or

```
BOOL isInteger = !fmod(fVal, 1.0);
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe it's the simplest way to check it:

```
if( fnum == (int)fnum ) {
    //fnum has integer value without decimals
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I personally like

```
 #define F_ISWHOLENUM(_float) (!fmod(_float, 1.0f))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
float number = myNum.floatValue;
 CFNumberType numberType = CFNumberGetType((CFNumberRef)myNum);
if(number == floorf(number) && (number == 1 || number == 0))
{
    // It is a bool (Exceptions 1.000, 0.00000)
}
else
{
    // It is some other number use numberTyoe here except kCFNumberCharType
    if (numberType == kCFNumberSInt32Type) {

    }
}
```